# Exception ignored in: 'ray.raylet.is simple_value' OverflowError: value too large to convert to int

Tags: ray

I am using Ray for distributed computation, however, when I feed in a Ray remote function with data around 3.5 GB, Ray gives me an error:

```
Exception ignored in: 'ray.raylet.is simple_value' OverflowError: value too large to convert to int
```

For example:

```
import ray
@ray.remote(num_gpus=1)
def gpu_nums(input_):
    return input_
ray.shutdown()
ray.init()
ray.get(gpu_nums.remote(np.ones(1000000000)))
```

Do we have any solutions to this problem?

Comment: I can reproduce this, it looks like a bug in Ray. Should be fixed by https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/5325. Thanks a lot for bringing this up!